# AndroidStudio: flavor with a subset of assets folder

Tags: android, android-studio, android-assets, android-productflavors

I have an assets folder in main and three flavors. Each one of them needs to import only a subset of those files. However some of them needs to be shared.

Let's make an example.
My assets folder in main contains four subfolders: A,B,C,D
flavor1 must contain assets A,B,C
flavor2 must contain assets A,C,D
flavor3 must contain assets B,D

Is there a way to declare a subset of the main's assets folder for each flavor, avoiding to copy/paste each desired folder in every flavor assets' folder (thus avoiding replication)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle: How to create two applications for each flavor with different assets folders:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881266/gradle-how-to-create-two-applications-for-each-flavor-with-different-assets-fol)

Comment: that could be, but mine is older...

Answer (score 0):

At last I finally managed to do that using sourceSets.