# How to create two applications for each flavor with different assets folders in Gradle?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Currently I'm working on an application that has  5 flavors and this is the part of my build.gradle files that matters:

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
       mavenCentral()
   }
   dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.0'
   }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("")
            storePassword "password"
            keyAlias "alias"
            keyPassword "password"
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 20

        applicationId 'application.package'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        flavor1{
            applicationId 'com.flavor1.package'
        }
        flavor2{
            applicationId 'com.flavor2.package'
        }
        flavor3{
            applicationId 'com.flavor3.package'
        }
        flavor4{
            applicationId 'com.flavor4.package'
        }
        flavor5{
            applicationId 'com.flavor5.package'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':SDK')
}
```

I had to make some changes in the file, but basically this is it.

**The question:** I have a requirement to provide for each one of those flavors a different set of assets files in the assets folder that will create a different apk file but will have the same package name. Those apk files will be uploaded to the Google play as the same application but for different regions.

So the package name have to stay the same. So basically I need to create a mechanism that instead of 5 flavors will created 10 flavor when every two of them have the same package name but a different assets folder. How can this be done using gradle?

I have tried implementing this using BuildTypes like so:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        sourceSets.main.assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }
    releaseAlt {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        sourceSets.main.assets.srcDirs = ['assetsalt']
    }
}
```

But for some reason the releaseAlt also takes the files located in the assets directory and not the assetsalt directory.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use buildTypes for that.

```
buildTypes {
  release {
    // ... the usual stuff here
  }
  releaseAlt {
    // .. the usual stuff here too like signing config etc...
  }
}
```

Now the file hierarchy :

You should have

```
project/
- app/
 - src/
  - main/
   - assets/
    - logo.png // Generic assets go here
   - java/
   - res/
   - ...

  - flavor1/
   - assets/
    - logo.png // Specific assets for all the flavor1 Variants

  - releaseAlt/
   - asset/
    - logo.png // Specific assets for all the releaseAlt Variants.

  - flavor1ReleaseAlt/
   - assets/
    - logo.png // very specific assets for the flavor1ReleaseAlt Variant
- SDK/
```

With this file hierarchy, when you build the `flavor1Release` variant, you will have the logo.png file from `flavor1/assets/`, but when you will build the `flavor1ReleaseAlt` variant, this png will be replaced by the on from `flavor1ReleaseAlt/assets/` folder.

**Explanation :**

Gradle is using conventions over configurations (by default). Especially when it comes to project structure. When the flavor1ReleaseAlt Variant is being built, Gradle (the Android-plugin actually ;) ) is looking for a folder called flavor1ReleaseAlt/ with some assets, resources, java etc... inside. Theses are the most specific app resources that Gradle could find for this Variant. Then Gradle will look for a folder simply called flavor1/ for some less specifics app resources. Then to an even lesser specific folder called releaseAlt/ and finally to the generic folder (main/).

The different folders have to have very strict names in order to match the Variant lookup :

- flavorBuildType/. (order is important).
- flavor/
- buildType/
- main/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I was hoping for a solution in which I would not have to create a whole flavor again for an application with the same package, but to provide the same flavor with a different assets directory to create two apks that the only difference between them is this assets folder. Do you think this can be done without createing the flavor1ReleaseAlt flavor?

Comment: You don't have to create a new flavor. In Android Gradle, the concept of flavor is tied to the concept of Variant. A Variant is BuildType + Flavor. For example, if you have a buildType Debug and a Flavor flavor1, the full variant is flavor1Debug. With my solution, you are using a custom buildType to have more Variants on the same Flavors. You just have to define a new BuildType and all your already defined Flavors will have a new Variant.

Comment: With Gradle, the folder hierarchy is Variant-based. If you know that every Flavor are sharing the same assets for the ReleaseAlt BuildType, you can simply add a new folder `releaseAlt/assets/` and put all of your alternatives assets inside. Editing the answer

Comment: The problem is that not all alternative flavors will share the same alternative assets folder. I need to provide different assets folders for different flavors. That the reason that I wrote what I wrote in the second peace of code. Another problem is that I need that the alternative flavor will contain all the files from the flavor1 directory but to take the assets from the flavor1alt directory. I don't really understand from your explanation how this can be done. Could you elaborate more?

Comment: If you have a specific alternative asset that goes for flavor1 alternative build, put it in `flavor1ReleaseAlt/assets/` folder. If you have a specific alternative assets that goes for flavor 2 alt build, put it in `flavor2ReleaseAlt/assets/` folder.

Comment: The plugin is merging the assets of the different folder. Let's say that you have an asset in `flavor1ReleaseAlt/assets/` folder (a very specific one) and you have a bunch of assets for flavor 1 (regardless of the build type). Then all of these assets will go in `flavor1/assets/`folder. At build time, the plugin will start by taking all the assets from the most specific folder (`flavor1ReleaseAlt/assets/`), then it will take to a less specific folder (`flavor1/assets/`), then it will take to an even lesser specific folder (`releaseAlt/assets/`) to finally take the generic assets from `main/`

Comment: look: under the src folder lets say that currently I have flavor1 and flavor1alt folders. now flavor1 takes all the files it needs from the sdk library and adds to it other resource files including its own assets folder. What I need is that flavor1alt when it's build will take all the files it's need from the sdk will add to it the files that flavor1 has and the only change is that it will have it's own assets folder.

Comment: You will end up in the final APK with all the assets from flavor1ReleaseAlt, flavor1, releaseAlt and main. Everything is merged automagically.

Comment: That what I'm trying to do, but for some reason when I build the flavor1alt apk. it take the sdk files and the alternative assets folder but it does not have the additional resource files that are contained in the flavor1 folder. Now because I don't want to copy the same resource files from flavor1 fodler to flavor1alt folder... I want it to go to flavor1 folder and take the resource files from there as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64793/discussion-between-pdegand59-and-emil-adz).

Comment: By the way, last question, from your knowledge is this mechanism is case sensitive? 
meaning if called the folder flavor1releasealt would it still work?

Comment: From what i tested a while ago, the folder naming is not case sensitive. It might have changed. You can't name a flavor or a buildType main or androidTest because theses names are reserved by the android plugin.

Comment: Ok, So I guess It's better to test it again... And it makes sense that you wouldn't be able to call them this way :)